# Grails Vaadin: Vaadin UI and REST Services

Tags: rest, grails, vaadin

I have a small application with a scaffold frontend and a RESTful Controller. I have switched to a Vaadin frontend and now the REST service is unreachable since the url mappings have been removed. Any chance to get it back without running a second application with the domain classes as plugin?

Comment: If they are in the same WEB-INFO folder then sure. You just have to make the correct entries in web.xml

Comment: please check in ``grails-app/conf/VaadinConfig.groovy`` the ``vaadin.mapping``.  If this does not bring you on the right tracks, please let us see your urlmappings and the vaadinmapping.

Comment: I did not know that Vaadin and Grails url mappings can coexist. I created seperate prefixes (/ui and /admin) and every thing works well.